# Using formula to count number of cycles in undirected graph in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cycle, discrete-mathematics

I came across this formula to get the number of 4-cycle in an undirected graph:

```
 [![formula to calculate the number of 4-cycle][1]][1]

 Ck = 1/2k Tr(Pk-1 A)

 k stands for k-cycle, and A is the adjacency matrix, Pk-1 is the path count matrix
```

the webpage link:

[mathWorld]http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html

I am now trying to code this simple formula in python, I could use NetworkX's adjacency_matrix function to get the adjacency matrix, and I could get the matrix trace too. I am just not sure about the so-called matrix of path count Pk, I googled a while but found no direct explanation on this.Could experts suggest what this Pk matrix is and  I wonder if it is possible to code it in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `P_k = A^k`. But as you are interested in the number of 4 cycles you can simply use the formula (3) of your [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html):

```
8c_4 = Tr(A^4) - 2m - 2 \sum_i{i\ne j} a_{ij}^{(2)}
```

where `a_{ij}^{(2)}` are the elements of `A^2`.

This formula should be easily implementable via `numpy`.

Comment: thank you. But I am not sure what A^2 are...Is it half of the adjacency matrix ?

Comment: That are matrix powers, e.g. `A^2 = A*A`, where the later is the matrix multiplication (`A^4 = A*A*A*A`) and `A` is the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Thank you, this is of tremendous help!